# What is a CA21A cable?

Tags: cable

What does **CA** stand for?

Why is it numbered **21**?

**Who** standardized it?

The abbreviation is used by Cisco for a cable called RJ-21X/CA21A that is used to connect an RJ-21 port on a voice gateway to a patch panel for analog phones. Since there are many other cables such as CA2DA, CA2EA, CA2FA, CA2GA, CA2HA, CA26A, CA27A, I assume that there's a standard.

Comment: I performed a google search on "CA21A" and got these [results](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=CA21A) which linked to [this](www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/.../vg350higcabl.pdf) document.

Comment: I'm aware of that document. A simple search doesn't answer my question. I've tried it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no RJ21X/CA21A cable.

But there are cables that have a CA21A connector. CA21A is a name used for RJ21X in Canada. There is a set of designations that correspond to Registered Jacks. For example, CA45A corresponds to RJ45S, CA11A corresponds to RJ11C.

Who standardized it? I cannot tell who originally standardized it. However, there is a list of the Certification and Engineering Bureau in Canada at [ic.gc.ca](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/ceb-bhst.nsf/eng/h_tt00049.html) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141016084418/http://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/ceb-bhst.nsf/eng/h_tt00049.html)'s a backup at web.archive.org.

What is it used for? The CA21A (RJ-21X) end of a cable terminates multiple two-wire copper lines for analog telephony or DSL over POTS.

Comment: Answering my own questions seems odd. I gave Keltari and andacejavelin points because their answers are useful.

Answer (score 2):

CA stands for [Console and Auxiliary](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/vg350/hardware/installation/guide/vg350_hig/vg350higcabl.pdf)

21 is for Registered Jack 21 ([RJ21](http://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/specialty))

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#History_and_authority):

> Registration interfaces were created by the Bell System under a 1976
>   Federal Communications Commission order for the standard
>   interconnection between telephone company equipment and customer
>   premises equipment. These interfaces used newly standardized jacks and
>   plugs, primarily based on miniature modular connectors.

Comment: It's also called a 25 pair amp or amphenol cable, from a common manufacturer of the end crimped on the cable (like all cotton swabs are often called Q-tips). It comes in multiple varieties and often referred to by the type of end... Male to female, male to male, female to pigtail (meaning no connector on one end for manual termination to connecting blocks)